# How to use SUBSTRING using REGEXP in MySQL

Tags: mysql, regular-expression

I have the following situation. I have to substring regular expression from description using MySQL.
Description:

> Lorem **D9801** ipsum dolor sit amet

Where D9801 is REGEXP. Every **strong text** description has different content but my regexp should looks like: REGEXP 'D[[:digit:]]{4}'

REGEXP always has "D" at the beginning and "xxxx" - 4 digits at the end: Dxxxx

I know the REGEXP returns only true/false value, but how can I make query to return only 'D9801' value?

I tried something like this:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING (description, LOCATE(REGEXP 'D[[:digit:]]{4}', description), 5)
FROM (
   SELECT "Lorem D9801 ipsum dolor sit amet" AS description
) temp
```

I know it's wrong, so I try with this:

```
SELECT 
    id, 
    SUM(description REGEXP 'D[[:digit:]]{4}') AS matches, 
    CASE
        WHEN (SUM(description REGEXP 'D[[:digit:]]{4}') > 0) THEN 
            SUBSTRING(description, LOCATE( /*POSITION_OF_REGEXP_IN_DESC*/ , description), 5)
        ELSE 'Brak schematu'
    END AS show_substr FROM ps_description GROUP BY id;
```

But how to find position of regexp?

I heard about UDF but I cannot use it, I use OVH hosting.

Comment: This is basically a dup of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4021507/mysql-use-regex-to-extract-string

Comment: Without using a UDF there is no built in functionality to retrieve the matched pattern from the REGEXP function and the other matching methods rely on knowing the full string you are matching for which doesnt work in this situation

Answer (score 4):

This would need to use the `LOCATE` and `SUBSTRING` syntax to get the information out of the string.
The basic locate syntax you would need is explained [here](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-locate-function.php).

LOCATE (search str, str, [position])

> search str = A string which will be searched for.
>
> str =A string which is going to be searched.
>
> position (optional)= Position from where (within the second argument) the searching will start .

While the substring function you need is explained [here](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-substring-function.php)

SUBSTRING(str, pos, len)

> str=  A string.
>
> pos=  Starting position.
>
> len=  Length in characters.

The easier way of viewing this is to think of substring as the following
SUBSTRING(str FROM pos FOR len)

The sytax I used to get the second word is below, I took advantage of the spaces that are constantly around the second word you are trying to extract.

```
declare @String varchar(50) ='Lorem D9801 ipsum dolor sit amet'

SUBSTRING
(
@String,
LOCATE(' ', @String),
LOCATE(' ', @String, (LOCATE(' ', @String) + 1)) - LOCATE(' ', @String)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, MySQL's regular expression function return true, false or null depending if the expression exists or not.

The trick in effecting the desired behavior is to determine which substring begins with the character you care about, has the correct length, and is followed by a number.  A series of substring_index functions are used to extract the string...

```
set @string:='Lorem D9801 ipsum dolor sit amet';
select
case when @string like '% D____ %' and cast((@num:= substring_index(substring_index(@string,concat(substring_index(@string,' D',1),' D'),-1),' ',1)) as signed) between '0' and '9999' then concat('D',@num)
     when @string like '% D% D____ %' and cast((@num:= substring_index(substring_index(@string,concat(substring_index(@string,' D',2),' D'),-1),' ',1)) as signed) between '0' and '9999' then concat('D',@num)
     when @string like '% D% D% D____ %' and cast((@num:= substring_index(substring_index(@string,concat(substring_index(@string,' D',3),' D'),-1),' ',1)) as signed) between '0' and '9999' then concat('D',@num)
     when @string like '% D% D% D% D____ %' and cast((@num:= substring_index(substring_index(@string,concat(substring_index(@string,' D',4),' D'),-1),' ',1)) as signed) between '0' and '9999' then concat('D',@num)
     when @string like '% D% D% D% D% D____ %' and cast((@num:= substring_index(substring_index(@string,concat(substring_index(@string,' D',5),' D'),-1),' ',1)) as signed) between '0' and '9999' then concat('D',@num)
end as test_case;
+-----------+
| test_case |
+-----------+
| D9801     |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```